# How to draw new layer on ImageView using Universal-Image-Loader

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview, ondraw, universal-image-loader

we use Universal Image Loader (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in our project. We use it to load images on gridview. But, we want to, on all of images new transparent layer and text description on it. When we override onDraw method we have this layer, but it is visible only when we scroll gridview.

Is it possible to draw new layer on ImageView using this library? We noticed that for new android devices >14, code works as expected, but not on emulator and not on previous versions of the system.

ProductView.java

```
public class ProductView extends ImageView {
    private Product product;
    private Paint p = new Paint();
    private Context context;

    public ProductView(Context context, Product product) {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        setId(product.getProductId());
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300));
        this.product = product;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Integer width = (int)canvas.getWidth();
        Integer height = (int)canvas.getHeight();

        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p.setAlpha(80);
        canvas.drawRect(0, (int)(height*0.73), width, height, p);
        p.setAlpha(100);
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setTextSize(16);
        p.setFakeBoldText(true);
        StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(product.getProductName(), new TextPaint(p), width-10,
                                        Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,(float)1.0, (float)0.0,
                                        true);
        canvas.translate(5, (int)(height*0.73));
        layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

ImageGridActivity.java

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends Activity implements SlideMenuInterface.OnSlideMenuItemClickListener {
[...]

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        [...]
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewAC);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageGridUniwersalAdapter(this, imageLoader, products.productList, options));
        gridView.setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, true, true));
    }
[...]   
}
```

ImageGridUniwersalAdapter.java

```
public class ImageGridUniwersalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private final List<Product> products;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    public ImageGridUniwersalAdapter(Context context, ImageLoader imageLoader, List<Product> products, DisplayImageOptions options){
        this.options = options;
        this.products = products;
        this.imageLoader = imageLoader;
        this.context = context;
    }

    [...]

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Product tmpProd = products.get(position);

        ProductView pv = new ProductView(this.context, tmpProd);
        imageLoader.displayImage(
                SettingsHelper.SERVERURL+tmpProd.getImgThumbUri(),
                pv,
                options);

        return pv;
    }
}
```

grid_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/gridviewAC"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:horizontalSpacing="4dip"
          android:numColumns="2"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
          android:verticalSpacing="4dip"
          android:padding="4dip" />
```

Comment: Why don't you use ImageView and TextView over this ImageView (both them are in FramLayout)?

Comment: Yes, you right. It's obvious. Thank you.